# How to represent an object at 25 differents dates

Tags: geoserver, sld

So basically, I have a map at day D. On this day X objects are represented with a color and full opacity.

What I'd like to do is to be able to represent on this map the Y objects present on the map at D-1, D-2, ..., D-25, on which I ll apply a gradually decreasing opacity.

Currently, I bound an SLD file to my layer with 25 rules. A rule define the opacity and the color of the object (1 rule for 1 day, so a rule for D-1, a rule for D-2 etc).

But this is not working, as geoserver is giving me back a `GC overhead limit exceeded` error.

Is there any other way to do it ? I may be unclear, so feel free to ask for more details, I ll edit my post.

EDIT : heres a peek at my SLD.

This is the rule I repeat 25 times in my SLD file. 
What change between each rule are the variables `dateXmin` and `dateXmax` who become `dateXminJ1` and `dateXmaxJ1` and so on 'till `dateXminJ25` and `dateXmaxJ25`.

For the record I have a SLD file that repeat this rule 3 times, and Geoserver is giving me back an image almost instantly.

```
<FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <Name>style_update_img</Name>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:And>
                            <ogc:Or>
                                <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                                    <ogc:PropertyName>table_name</ogc:PropertyName>
                                    <ogc:Function name="env"><ogc:Literal>name1</ogc:Literal><ogc:Literal>default</ogc:Literal></ogc:Function>
                                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>

                                <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                                    <ogc:PropertyName>table_name</ogc:PropertyName>
                                    <ogc:Function name="env"><ogc:Literal>name2</ogc:Literal><ogc:Literal>default</ogc:Literal></ogc:Function>
                                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>

                                <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                                    <ogc:PropertyName>table_name</ogc:PropertyName>
                                    <ogc:Function name="env"><ogc:Literal>name3</ogc:Literal><ogc:Literal>default</ogc:Literal></ogc:Function>
                                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>

                                <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                                    <ogc:PropertyName>table_name</ogc:PropertyName>
                                    <ogc:Function name="env"><ogc:Literal>name4</ogc:Literal><ogc:Literal>default</ogc:Literal></ogc:Function>
                                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>

                                <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                                    <ogc:PropertyName>table_name</ogc:PropertyName>
                                    <ogc:Function name="env"><ogc:Literal>name5</ogc:Literal><ogc:Literal>default</ogc:Literal></ogc:Function>
                                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>

                                <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                                    <ogc:PropertyName>table_name</ogc:PropertyName>
                                    <ogc:Function name="env"><ogc:Literal>name6</ogc:Literal><ogc:Literal>default</ogc:Literal></ogc:Function>
                                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>

                                <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                                    <ogc:PropertyName>table_name</ogc:PropertyName>
                                    <ogc:Function name="env"><ogc:Literal>name7</ogc:Literal><ogc:Literal>default</ogc:Literal></ogc:Function>
                                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>

                                <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                                    <ogc:PropertyName>table_name</ogc:PropertyName>
                                    <ogc:Function name="env"><ogc:Literal>name8</ogc:Literal><ogc:Literal>default</ogc:Literal></ogc:Function>
                                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>

                                <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                                    <ogc:PropertyName>table_name</ogc:PropertyName>
                                    <ogc:Function name="env"><ogc:Literal>name9</ogc:Literal><ogc:Literal>default</ogc:Literal></ogc:Function>
                                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>

                                <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                                    <ogc:PropertyName>table_name</ogc:PropertyName>
                                    <ogc:Function name="env"><ogc:Literal>name10</ogc:Literal><ogc:Literal>default</ogc:Literal></ogc:Function>
                                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            </ogc:Or>

                            <ogc:And>
                                <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
                                    <ogc:PropertyName>daterec</ogc:PropertyName>
                                    <ogc:Function name="strConcat">
                                        <ogc:Function name="env"><ogc:Literal>dateXmin</ogc:Literal><ogc:Literal>2017-01-01</ogc:Literal></ogc:Function><ogc:Literal>T00:00:00.0Z</ogc:Literal>
                                    </ogc:Function>
                                </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
                                <ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
                                    <ogc:PropertyName>daterec</ogc:PropertyName>
                                    <ogc:Function name="strConcat">
                                        <ogc:Function name="env"><ogc:Literal>dateXmax</ogc:Literal><ogc:Literal>2017-01-01</ogc:Literal></ogc:Function><ogc:Literal>T00:00:00.0Z</ogc:Literal>
                                    </ogc:Function>
                                </ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
                            </ogc:And>
                        </ogc:And>
                    </ogc:Filter>

                    <PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <Geometry>
                            <ogc:Function name="buffer">
                                <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
                                <ogc:Function name="env"><ogc:Literal>buffer</ogc:Literal><ogc:Literal>200</ogc:Literal></ogc:Function>
                            </ogc:Function>
                        </Geometry>

                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">
                                <ogc:Function name="strConcat">
                                    <ogc:Literal>#</ogc:Literal><ogc:Function name="env"><ogc:Literal>color</ogc:Literal><ogc:Literal>B9121B</ogc:Literal></ogc:Function>                                     
                                </ogc:Function>
                            </CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">
                                <ogc:Literal>0.92</ogc:Literal>
                            </CssParameter>
                        </Fill>            
                    </PolygonSymbolizer>

                    <LineSymbolizer>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">
                                <ogc:Literal>#</ogc:Literal><ogc:Function name="env"><ogc:Literal>color</ogc:Literal><ogc:Literal>B9121B</ogc:Literal></ogc:Function>
                            </CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-opacity">
                                <ogc:Literal>0.87</ogc:Literal>
                            </CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                    </LineSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
```

Comment: just increase the memory available - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41742058/geoserver-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded

Comment: @iant The error is not raise, but I don't even reach the end of the map loading..

Comment: did you increase the amount of memory?

Comment: Yes, from 1024 to 2048. But geoserver is taking way to long to generate my image.

Comment: then you can turn up the time out, or speed up the map draw with an index or fix the sld but then we'd need to see some of it

Comment: @iant I've updated my answer, providing the revelant part of my SLD.

Comment: I'd recommend to switch the logging level to "geotools developer logging" and see what query gets sent into the database. My guess is that the filter is too complex and it's not getting encoded into SQL, leaving to the loading of the whole dataset in that area. The usage of filter functions can also be part of the problem (if you are using postgis, do try enabling the function encoding flag in the datastore options).

Answer (score 0):

You can handle time natively in GeoServer.

Read [this article in the manual about doing it](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/time.html).

I haven't got a vector layer immediately available to demonstrate it, but you can set it up on the 'Dimensions' tab for a layer.

Once set, it's simply another parameter in your WMS request. You may have luck using one of the [Leaflet plugins](https://github.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension) that handles time.

Comment: that won't show them dimming over time though (with out the SLD file)

Comment: I've looked into it, and I don't see how it could help me with my problem.